# Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 & AspNetCore 3.1 Angular Template Error

Tags: angular, visual-studio, automapper

Creating an AspNetCore 3.1 Angular template with Authorisation for individual accounts in Visual Studio Community Edition 2019 throws an error in the error list:

*Package AutoMapper 9.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package AutoMapper 9.0.0 does not support any target frameworks.*

Any assistance will be greatly received!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing AutoMapper version 10 but it was momentarily annoying that it didn't work straight out of the box.